# Passing a function to a class in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to pass a function to a class and then call it from the class. Here is my code:

```
class TestClass {
    var action:()

    init( action:())
    {
        self.action = action
    }
}

func doSomething()
{
    println("need to do something")
}


let testingFunction = TestClass(action:doSomething())
testingFunction.action
```

When I call testingFunction.action nothing happens. Any suggestion.

Comment: You're not passing a function, you're passing the result of calling a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function type contains the parameter types and the return type. In this case, `doSomething` has a function type of `() -> Void`. `Void` is an empty tuple, so this is equivalent to `() -> ()`. So your `TestClass` would look like this:

```
class TestClass {
    var action: () -> Void
    init(action: () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
    }
}
```

To pass a function as a parameter, simply use the name of the function just like the name of any other variable. So you would initialize `TestClass` like this:

```
let testingFunction = TestClass(action: doSomething)
```

and call the action function like this:

```
testingFunction.action()
```

See the [Swift Language Guide section on function types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_270) for more information.